# Infinispan local cache error: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.globalstate.impl.GlobalConfigurationManagerImpl.start()

Tags: infinispan

I have upgraded a Spring boot service to Infinispan 9.4.16.Final from 5.2.20.Final. The service has two XML files. I used the conversion script to convert them. Both have `local-cache` entries and no other types of caches. One was left with empty `transport` element by the conversion tool.

When we deploy and run these services, we often see this warning at startup:

`org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.globalstate.impl.GlobalConfigurationManagerImpl.start() on object of type GlobalConfigurationManagerImpl`

The above is the first warning/error we see. There is no stack trace. Why would it be calling GlobalConfigurationManagerImpl when we're only using local cache?

A few lines later in the log, then I see many `The cache has been stopped and invocations are not allowed!` errors. The last error we see is as follows. The service fails to start up successfully.

`Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache org.infinispan.CONFIG on <server_name>`

Why are these errors/warnings happening on startup? Is there a problem in the config files? I've searched online and have not found a solution.

~~**More Info**~~~

Here is one of the two XML config files:

```
<infinispan
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "urn:infinispan:config:9.4 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-9.4.xsd"
   xmlns = "urn:infinispan:config:9.4">

    <threads/>
    <cache-container name = "TestCenterServiceCache">
<!-- The conversion tool added this empty "transport" element. It was not present in our old config file -->
        <transport/>
        <jmx domain = "org.infinispan.TestCenterServiceCache"/>
        <local-cache name = "authorizedLocations">
            <expiration lifespan = "3600000"/>
        </local-cache>

        <!--caching for 24 hours: 3,600,000 milliseconds/hr x 24 hours -->
        <local-cache name = "proximitySearchConfiguration">
            <expiration lifespan = "86400000"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

The above is instantiated via applicationContext.xml. The first warning (`GlobalConfigurationManagerImpl.start()`) is referencing these beans.

```
<bean id="infinispanCacheManager"
          class="org.infinispan.spring.embedded.support.InfinispanEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean"
          p:configurationFileLocation="classpath:testCenterServices-cache-config.xml" />

    <bean id="cacheManager"
          class="org.infinispan.spring.embedded.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="infinispanCacheManager" />
    </bean>
```

Here is the second XML config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<infinispan
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "urn:infinispan:config:9.4 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-9.4.xsd"
   xmlns = "urn:infinispan:config:9.4">

    <threads />
    <cache-container name="AtlasServicesCacheManager">
        <local-cache name="allLocaleCache" />
        <local-cache name="localeCacheByID" />

        <local-cache name="countryByCode" />
        <local-cache name="allActiveCountries" />
        <local-cache name="allCountries" />

        <local-cache name="allStatesForCountryCode" />
        <local-cache name="allActiveStatesForCountryCode" />
        <local-cache name="stateForCountryCodeStateCode" />
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

The above is instantiated via java code.

```
    @Bean(name="atlasServicesCacheManager")
    public CacheManager makeCacheManager() throws IOException {
        return new SpringEmbeddedCacheManager(new DefaultCacheManager("atlas-cache-config.xml"));
    }
```

I don't know if it's meaningful, but only after the upgrade, we log messages that include "JGroups", such as `Unable to use any JGroups configuration mechanisms provided in properties {}. Using default JGroups configuration!`.

The service instances are running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (Windows 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, remove the empty `<transport />` element for local caches.

Adding that empty element seems to be a defect in the `config-converter`. With the empty `transport` element in place, it seems that Infinispan is partially configured for cluster synchronization. For details on the underlying issue, see bug report: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-11854.